# How to add javascript in page_load

Tags: javascript, c#, onkeyup

I have javascript code that mask my data in textbox by onkeyup event .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("<%= yourTextbox.ClientID %>").onkeyup = function() {
    if (/^[0-9]{2}(.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(this.value)) {
        this.value += ".";
    }
}
<script>
```

But I have error

> Runtime Error JavaScript: Failed to set property "onkeyup" reference
>   value is not defined or is NULL.

What i need to add in my code to make this work?
Asp.net c# framework 2.0 javascript

Comment: Where did you put the script tag?

Comment: @Davide Lettieri I put it in the head .
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in C# code on PageLoad

```
yourTextbox.Attributes.Add("onkeyup","myFun('"+yourTextbox.ClientID+"');");
```

in Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myFun(obj) {
    if (/^[0-9]{2}(.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(obj.value)) {
        obj.value += ".";
    }
}
<script>
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work . My texbox names "dr" .
`code` protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 dr.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "myFun('"+dr+"');");
}

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function myFun(obj) {
             if (/^[0-9]{2}(.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(obj.value)) {
                 this.value += ".";
             }
         }
      </script>

Comment: @AndreyGolubtsov use Firebug from mozilla for debugging

Comment: thanks ! My problem was : i think that yourTextbox.ClientID mean yourTextbox .

Answer (score 0):

You must try to add the event with addEventListener.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("onkeyup", function(){
        if (/^[0-9]{2}(.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(this.value)) {
            this.value += ".";
        }
    });
```

Comment: it breaks with error  : Runtime Error JavaScript: Failed to set property "onkeyup" reference value is not defined or is NULL"

Comment: did you replace the getElementById("myBtn") with getElementById("<%= yourTextbox.ClientID %>")? I forgot to replace it in the example.

Comment: My code now :
`<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                     document.getElementById("dr").addEventListener("onkeyup", function () {
                         if (/^[0-9]{2}(.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(this.value)) {
                             this.value += ".";
                         }
                     });  </script> `

` dr.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "myFun('"+dr+"');");`

P.s. my textbox name "dr"

Comment: The id is not Content1? I think it must be: `document.getElementById("Content1").addEventListener("onkeyup", function () { if (/^[0-9]{2}(.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(this.value)) { this.value += "."; } });`

Comment: No . Element is textbox .I write it to show in what place consider my <script> . I need to mask textbox data in onkeyup event .